# how to pass a List in the model as a parameter of an ajax call?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i use MVC 4 ASP.net with Razor views.

So with my ajax call i want to refine my search results. However atm i do this by creating methods in the controller that connect with the database and include ALL the search filters. This is not practical however because the method contains a huge switch case with all sorts of switch cases inside.

This is not practical so my qeustion is how can i retrieve the table information runtime in the View? i know how to pass parameters with my AJAX method and have used this to access a method that goes to the database. It's however better to get the current view his list and modify that one. Basically i want to change all the database calls to the list i get in the parameter so i can adjust stuff in that list rather than connecting to the database after each filter i just have no clue how to pass on the current list in the view

here's my AJAX call:

```
$(checkbox5yearsfilter).click(function () {
  if ($(checkbox5yearsfilter).is(':checked')) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../Person/changeTableOnWorkExp',
      datatype: 'html',
      data: { parameter: $('#parameter').val(), choice: $('#choice').val(), years: 5, ischecked: "yes" },
      success: function (data) {
        $('span div.searchresults').html(data);
      },
      error: function (data) {
        alert("Something went wrong with the call, have you searched already?");
      }
    });
  }
```

and here's my method which is WAY too long:

```
public PartialViewResult changeTableOnWorkExp(string parameter, string choice, int years, string ischecked)
{
  List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
  if (ischecked == "yes")
  {
    switch (years)
    {
      case 5:
        switch(choice)
        {
          case "Knows Already":
            list = (from p in db.Persons where p.YearsOfWorkExperience > 5 && (p.HobbyProjectICTRelated.Contains(parameter) || p.LearntSkillsAndLevelOfSkills.Contains(parameter)) select p).ToList();
            return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
          case "Wants To Learn":
            list = (from p in db.Persons where p.YearsOfWorkExperience > 5 && p.SkillsToLearn.Contains(parameter) select p).ToList();
            return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
          case "Hobbies":
            list = (from p in db.Persons where p.YearsOfWorkExperience > 5 && p.Hobbys.Contains(parameter) select p).ToList();
            return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
          case "Name":
            list = (from p in db.Persons where p.YearsOfWorkExperience > 5 && p.Name.Contains(parameter) select p).ToList();
            return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
        }
        break;
      case 10:
        switch(choice)
        {
          case "Knows Already":
            list = (from p in db.Persons where p.YearsOfWorkExperience > 10 && (p.HobbyProjectICTRelated.Contains(parameter) || p.LearntSkillsAndLevelOfSkills.Contains(parameter)) select p).ToList();
            return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
          case "Wants To Learn":
            list = (from p in db.Persons where p.YearsOfWorkExperience > 10 && p.SkillsToLearn.Contains(parameter) select p).ToList();
            return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
          case "Hobbies":
            list = (from p in db.Persons where p.YearsOfWorkExperience > 10 && p.Hobbys.Contains(parameter) select p).ToList();
            return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
          case "Name":
            list = (from p in db.Persons where p.YearsOfWorkExperience > 10 && p.Name.Contains(parameter) select p).ToList();
            return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
         }
         break;
       case 15:
         switch(choice)
         {
           case "Knows Already":
             list = (from p in db.Persons where p.YearsOfWorkExperience > 15 && (p.HobbyProjectICTRelated.Contains(parameter) || p.LearntSkillsAndLevelOfSkills.Contains(parameter)) select p).ToList();
             return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
           case "Wants To Learn":
             list = (from p in db.Persons where p.YearsOfWorkExperience > 15 && p.SkillsToLearn.Contains(parameter) select p).ToList();
             return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
           case "Hobbies":
             list = (from p in db.Persons where p.YearsOfWorkExperience > 15 && p.Hobbys.Contains(parameter) select p).ToList();
             return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
           case "Name":
             list = (from p in db.Persons where p.YearsOfWorkExperience > 15 && p.Name.Contains(parameter) select p).ToList();
             return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
         }
         break;
       default:
         list = null;
         return null;
     }
     return null;
   }
   else
   {
     list = getListPerson(parameter, choice);
     return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Is it neccesary to write that java script of the ajax call on your own? Why don't you use the ajax-helpers of asp.net?

Comment: By the way: you should refactor the code and return the PartialView at the and of the methode and in the switches just set the list.

Comment: this worked so i left it like this but i guess i can use the helper still doesn't answer my qeustion though

Comment: Passing the collection back to the controller to do the filtering would mean rendering controls for each property of each item in the collection and posting it all back which would be crazy. It could be hundreds of times slower than calling the database. You could put the collection in session to avoid the database call each time.

Comment: it might be slower but i'll have to pass over 10 filters with the method then... and that is for readability of the code a huge drama so it might not be the best way but for the readability of the code it's 10x better if not 100x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify the controller code and delete the outer switch by first creating a collection based on the `year` parameter

```
public PartialViewResult changeTableOnWorkExp(string parameter, string choice, int years, string ischecked)
{
  var list = (from p in db.Persons where p.YearsOfWorkExperience > years select p).AsEnumerable();
  switch(choice)
  {
    case "Knows Already":
    list =  list.Where(p => p.HobbyProjectICTRelated.Contains(parameter) || p.LearntSkillsAndLevelOfSkills.Contains(parameter));
    case "Wants To Learn":
    ....
  }
  return PartialView("_SearchSkills", list);
}
```

Note also you could store the unfiltered `Persons` collection in session in the initial GET method and use that rather than making a database call each time.

Comment: how do i store it in the session within the GET method?

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading the question correctly you want to return a `JsonResult` and just return a `List<Persons>`. You'll then get that result and bind it to whatever you are displaying the results in: a grid, list, etc.

You'll likely want to look into some sort of client templating library to make this easier. You can certainly use jQuery to do all this, but something like [handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com/) would make it much easier. If you are displaying results in a grid, [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/) is pretty nice.